# Как правильно подключить класс UserTable

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

возникает ошибка при вызова метода Class '\Agents\Bitrix\Main\UserTable' not found,

как правильно подключить класс UserTable ?

use \Bitrix\Main\UserTable; так пробовал, не работает

Answer (score 0):

`\Bitrix\Main\UserTable` это часть модуля main, он всегда подключен.

Скорее всего ошибка из-за того, что в контексте пространства имен `\Agents` используется класс `Bitrix\Main\UserTable` вместо `\Bitrix\Main\UserTable`.